# Access control in ethereum

Tags: solidity, truffle, transactions, ether, network

Can you let some nodes in ethereum network have only view access while others can to mine blocks and add them to blockchain? Can the miners be authorized nodes only?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure a Proof of Authority blockchain only the authorized validators will be able to mine blocks, everyone else will not be able to generate new blocks.